# Escape curly braces in LOG4Js - replace{pattern}{regex}{substitution}

Tags: log4j2, logback

I want to replace the starting brace from my json %msg

Say %msg evaluvates to:

```
{ "key1": "val1", "key2":"val2" }
```

Once replaced I want it be become:

```
"key1": "val1", "key2":"val2" }
```

I tried using the pattern:

```
%replace{%msg}{\{}{}
```

But that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace with an empty string, use this.
Wrap your pattern with square brackets.

```
%replace{%msg}{[\{]}{}
```

[This doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) contain some useful information about regex patterns.